# Notepad++ Disable mouse-dragging of text

Tags: notepad++

It's possible to mistakenly drag text that was marked with the PC's mouse and hence "push" it to another place. Sometimes it will just be pushed to another place and sometimes it will jumble-up or mess existing text.

Is there a way to make sure text won't be dragged like this in `Notepad++`?

I ask since when working with program codes or scripts it's sometimes enough that one letter will be mistakenly dragged without noticing and all the program would stop working, and not always a debugger would find that root cause.

`Settings > Preferences > Check "Lock (no drag and drop)` doesn't help, even after restarting the program.

Comment: What language are you working on where moving a letter randomly in a file doesn't cause a syntax error? That would be quite an unfortunate fluke!

Comment: I played with it and unfortunately I have not found a solution and I believe there is no solution. I really hope someone proves me wrong.

Comment: I usually work with Unix Bash or JavaScript codes. I meant to say that not always a program would warn of syntax errors as not all progs do that not and surly not for all languages.

Comment: FYI the "Lock (no drag and drop)" option is for *tabs*, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before and the general answer seems to be no.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700696/how-to-disable-drag-drop-of-text-in-notepad

On the other hand you can mess with the drag and drop sensitivity in Windows (which will affect all programs and Windows Explorer). By doing this you can make it so that you really have to drag a lot before the drag and drop happens.

To do this you have to edit the registry. Here is a Microsoft article on how to do so: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/can-you-turn-off-drag-and-drop-in-windows-7/81804779-a061-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Once again keep in mind that this will affect all applications.